# Studying the convergence and absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} cos(2^n)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, absolute-convergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} cos(2^n)$$I have tried to use several convergence test without any results. Also, since $a_n=cos(2^n)$ always take positive values, $|a_n|=a_n$ and therefore if $a_n$ converges it also absolute converges, right?

Comment: $\cos(2)=-0.41614683\ldots$

Comment: Approximate $2\pi$ by a rational numbers of the form $p/2^n$ for arbitrarily large $n$. That will show you that $\cos(2^n)$ doesn't tend to zero.

Comment: What do you know about the rotations of the circle?

Comment: @Hellen I think you mean $\frac1\pi$ and the approximation must not be too bad

Comment: Consider $$\cos (2^{n+1}) = \cos^2 (2^n) - \sin^2(2^n).$$

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758340/does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-left-frac-cos2nn-right-converge-or-n).